# Case independent sorting

Tags: perl, hashtable, case-insensitive

How do I sort hash table by key (phonetically)
I mean, if there is 3 keys in the hash table (called `%tags`), `"MWE", "wPrefix", "conjunction"`, if I use the regular sort:

```
foreach $tag (sort keys %tags) {
    print "$tag\n";
}
```

The output I get is:

```
MWE
conjunction
wPrefix
```

But the output should be:

```
conjunction
MWE
wPrefix
```

Comment: I believe you mean a "case-insensitive" sort rather than a "phonetic" sort. If not, then you'll have to specify your preferred method for converting a word into a phonetic representation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the block code for sort function, comparing the upper case of each item:

```
foreach $tag (sort {uc($a) cmp uc($b)} keys %tags) {
    print "$tag\n";
}
```

This is a case-insensitive sorting, as @Dave Sherohman points

Comment: It's worth pointing out that Perl v16 has a proper case folding facility that works impartially with the full Unicode character set. You need `use feature 'fc'` (or `use 5.016`) and then `fc $a cmp fc $b`.

Comment: @Borodin Indeed so; there are definitely situations where using `uc` over `fc` yields the wrong answers. Moreover, even that doesn’t give reasonable results on non-casing items whose collation is poorly apprehended. Where do numbers go with respect to letters? What about the various symbols and punctuation, etc?

Comment: `fc` is also available on Perls older than 5.16 (but at least 5.8.1) by installing [Unicode::CaseFold](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::CaseFold).